# What are the rules for object positions when space is rotated in Fez?

Tags: fez

I'm trying to solve the cube puzzle room and noted that cubes kind of behave randomly when I move them and rotate space. For example, when I rotate move the left most cube forward (in the picture projection) by one step and then rotate back it falls down, though effectively it hasn't moved a bit in the shown projection.

[image]

So what are the rules to know where the cube will be placed after rotation?

Please note, I don't want to know the solution to the puzzle, my question is only about game mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

First, the cubes in this particular room are funny; when you enter the room, you will notice them slowly sliding across the floor and into place.

Also, I have played with the cubes in this room for some time, and I am unable to rotate and get cubes to fall down (although I recall in my first play-through a few years ago this happened... there *have* been several game updates since then).

---

In general, cubes will follow the same mechanics that hold for the rest of Fez:

- objects inherit the x/y/z-coordinates of the object they are standing on, or placed onto
- if an object is moved so that x/y-coordinates change, the z-coordinate is unchanged until the environment determines the object must be moved into the foreground; even then, coordinates are adjusted so there is as little change as possible
- when rotating, background objects (such as vines or fireplace platforms) may disappear into the foreground, causing your character to fall off them

---

*Please feel free to edit, and add other game mechanics to this list that have been missed.*

Answer (score -2):

(Note: This is not information from the wiki or source code, this is from my experience with purple block puzzles)
The game tracks 3d positions, so if you have a cube in the center of a platform and then move it to the edge, rotating will not cause it to forget that the cube has moved. However, putting a cube on a platform that it shouldn't be able to get onto will change its position in all 3 dimensions. Putting cubes on cubes behaves similarly, which can cause cubes to have seemingly random behaviors. Even though the cube's behavior may seem random, as far as I know, cubes will never actually BE random. If you've collected 32 cubes, then that would help you figure out what's going on.